# How do I get my sidebar to render to the left of my content instead of stacking the two components?

Tags: html, css, angular

I am trying to get the sidebar to be on the left side of the content and instead the two components stack on top of each other.

**the html I am using to style**

```
<div class="bg-gray-600 flex flex-col max-h-min">
    <div>
        <app-course-info-home></app-course-info-home>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-row">
        <div class="bg-blue-500 col-span-1" id="module-display">
            <app-module-display></app-module-display>
        </div>
        <div class="bg-yellow-200 max-w-min flex-col" id="course-sidebar">
            <app-course-sidebar></app-course-sidebar>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**The Output**
[Picture of the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8I35Y.png)
I want the black box to be all the way to the left like it is, but the top to be the max-h-screen. Then I want the blue box to be to the right of the black sidebar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that you're making use of flex layouts - that's good and, once you have them figured out, makes sorting page layouts so much easier. I highly recommend using [Angular-flex](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout) so that you don't have to play with styling directly, and it makes it easier to read.

An approximation of what you want - written using Angular-flex directives because that's what I can provide faster. Also, as I'm not entirely certain what each of your components relate to (other than the `app-course-sidebar`, I'm using placeholders).

```
<div class="bg-gray-600" fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="start stretch">
    <div>
        <app-course-info-home></app-course-info-home>
    </div>
    <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="stretch start">
        <div class="bg-yellow-200" id="course-sidebar">
            <app-course-sidebar></app-course-sidebar>
        </div>
        <div fxFlex class="bg-blue-500" id="module-display">
            <app-module-display></app-module-display>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

This layout should look something like

```
------------------------------------
[course info]
[sidebar] [-----module display-----]
------------------------------------
```

Note that the biggest change is in where your sidebar is within the template. Row layouts, without setting specific orders, are basic left-to-right one-after-another layouts. So if you want your sidebar on the left, put it as the first child.

The root div is column layout, so the course info div will be placed above the grouping div.
The grouping div is row layout, so the sidebar and module display child divs will be displayed besides each other.
The module display div makes use of `fxFlex` to make it take up whatever space it has available for width, pushing the sidebar to the left so much as it's able (control how severe that is by setting a min-width on that sidebar if you don't want it to look too squished).

Comment: Thank you so much! Wow it is good to ask questions! Thank you thank you thank you